# How to generate random string and put it in HashTable?

Tags: java, random, hashtable

I want to generate a random unique String and put in hashtable. I did like below code but it is not unique and it is just One Character .

```
while(k<4){
    for(int j=1 ; j<=13 ;j++){
        Hashtable<Integer, String> Deck = new Hashtable();  
        int myChar = (int) (Math.random()*str.length());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str.charAt(myChar)); 

        int i = (int) (Math.random() *52) ; 
        Deck.put(i, sb.toString());
        System.out.print(Deck);
    }

    System.out.println();
    k++;
}
```

output is this

```
{30=d}{9=e}{11=b}{10=d}{43=g}....
```

I want to be

```
{30=dea}{9=egt}{11=brf}{10=dgrtg}{43=grrh}{14=gwrt}.....
```

Comment: perhaps, `sb.append(str.charAt(myChar));`, you are only adding one . you can increase it's length `myChar+any int` supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons Lang to generate an alphabetic string

```
String generatedString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
```

Try something like this

```
    Hashtable<Integer, String> Deck = new Hashtable();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String generatedString = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
        int key = (int) (Math.random() *52) ;
        Deck.put(key, generatedString);
    }
    System.out.println(Deck);
```

OutPut

```
{9=Ut7N87oMNp, 8=7kbARh5WIy, 7=pbU2ZCOGK1, 6=vAGAIw41Us, 5=VLnpY1FAuN, 4=UEIJNIvZlt, 3=z6Y3zXcDY1, 2=PxaMqXl8XW, 1=l72bkPdY6T, 0=FFdOsKpQgd}
```

If you want only Alphabets then use `RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10);` instaed of `RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10)`.

If you dont want third party api, then its your code snippet with some changes

```
while (k < 4) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
            Hashtable<Integer, String> Deck = new Hashtable();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt++ != 10) {
                int myChar = (int) (Math.random() * str.length());
                sb.append(str.charAt(myChar));
            }
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
            Deck.put(i, sb.toString());
            System.out.print(Deck);
        }

        System.out.println();
        k++;
    }
```

Added while loop only...

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code to generate unique key using random method.

```
private char[] uniqueKeyGenerator(int len) {

        String Capital_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String Small_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String numbers = "0123456789";
        String values = Capital_chars + Small_chars + numbers;

        // Using random method
        Random rndm_method = new Random();
        char[] password = new char[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            password[i] = values.charAt(rndm_method.nextInt(values.length()));
        }
        return password;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random String by the using of below code.

```
private static final String ALPHA_STRING = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static String randomString(int count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (count-- != 0) {
        int character = (int) (Math.random() * ALPHA_STRING.length());
        builder.append(ALPHA_STRING.charAt(character));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Hashtable<Integer, String> Deck = new Hashtable();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            Deck.put(j, randomString(12));
    }
    System.out.println(Deck);


}
```

Output

```
{10=upjolkfihcyh, 9=irpbrcoclcmx, 8=ppugclscjlja, 7=wtnvkpmocuwd, 6=gpyzppvywazp, 5=vosixtjvcqlg, 4=plwtzzjpzeoq, 3=wsdyyppphhng, 2=knqdzfctfnez, 1=jzakqfiksrho}
```